# ImportError: cannot import name 'imread' from 'scipy.misc' with tensorflow 2.2

Tags: python, tensorflow, scipy

i am using tensorflow 2.2 in virtualenv, i tried to import imread, imresize from from scipy.misc but got this error
from scipy.misc import imread, imresize
when i checked for the reason online, i figured out that scipy.misc is deprecated with the version of scipy required in tf2.2.
So i tried using imageio but getting error of PIL
don't know what to do, can anyone of you help?

Comment: tensorflow does not require scipy, so you can install any version.

Comment: in tensorflow2.2 scipy is required it is one of the collected packages when i try to uninstall it an error occurred

Answer (score 0):

the answer to my question is quite simple. I needed to install all the required packages of tensorflow2.2 mentioned in the documentation and use python 64bits

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).